# Symfony2 Doctrine Extensions generating entities from YML

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use the Timestampable behaviour from Doctrine Extensions, I installed StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle to help me with that. But when I make my YML scheme and run the generate entities command, everything runs without errors, but in the generated php class no Gedmo/DoctrineExtensions annotations appear. What am I doing wrong?

This is the YML file I use for the simple issue tracker I want to make (Issue.orm.yml):

```
Theta\IssueTrackerBundle\Entity\Issue:
  type: entity
  table: issues
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    category:
      type: string
      length: 16
    created_at:
      type: datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
    updated_at:
      type: datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: update
    closed_at:
      type: datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable
    title:
      type: string
      length: 64
  oneToOne:
    user_id:
      targetEntity: ThetaUserBundle\User
    assigned_to:
      targetEntity: ThetaUserBundle\User
```

This is the generated php class (Issue.php):

```
namespace Theta\IssueTrackerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Issue
 */
class Issue
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $closed_at;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \ThetaUserBundle\User
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @var \ThetaUserBundle\User
     */
    private $assigned_to;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param string $category
     * @return Issue
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set created_at
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Issue
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->created_at = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created_at
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated_at
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return Issue
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated_at
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    /**
     * Set closed_at
     *
     * @param \DateTime $closedAt
     * @return Issue
     */
    public function setClosedAt($closedAt)
    {
        $this->closed_at = $closedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get closed_at
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getClosedAt()
    {
        return $this->closed_at;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Issue
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set user_id
     *
     * @param \ThetaUserBundle\User $userId
     * @return Issue
     */
    public function setUserId(\ThetaUserBundle\User $userId = null)
    {
        $this->user_id = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user_id
     *
     * @return \ThetaUserBundle\User 
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set assigned_to
     *
     * @param \ThetaUserBundle\User $assignedTo
     * @return Issue
     */
    public function setAssignedTo(\ThetaUserBundle\User $assignedTo = null)
    {
        $this->assigned_to = $assignedTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get assigned_to
     *
     * @return \ThetaUserBundle\User 
     */
    public function getAssignedTo()
    {
        return $this->assigned_to;
    }
}
```

The timestampable behaviour does not appear in the php class, and I don't understand why. I followed the instructions for installing the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle to the letter, and it seems to be installed correctly, but it doesn't do anything. I am using Symfony 2.2.

So my question: am I expecting something that is not supposed to happen, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Luc

Comment: were you able to find a way to get this to auto generate entities?  I was looking for the answer to this exact question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its works the same way for StofDoctrineExtensions but generally you would need to put the lifecyccallbacks in your yml.

```
    lifecycleCallbacks:
        postPersist: doSomething
        # callback   # method in entity
```

And then the annotations and the method name would match this.

Comment: I believe that that is the way to do it manually, the doctrine extensions should do this automatically if for example the timestampable property is added to a field. For now I'm back to doing it manually, but it would be great if all it takes is just adding it to the YML. Cannot find it anywhere in the Doctrine Extensions or the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle documentation...